# Filter comments from file opened in desktop editor on Windows

Tags: windows, bash

I was wondering if there was a way to omit comments from a text file opened on my desktop. If I had an editor session with the following:

```
\\this is a comment durdurdur
*Real code line here*
\\another comment
```

...the desired output would be an editor buffer containing only

```
*Real code line here*
```

Comment: Do you mean ignore such lines when reading, or modify the file in-place, or stream a modification, or[...]?

Comment: And what exactly does "open" file mean in this scenario? Does that mean you're intending to stream the update? To work from a file descriptor rather than a filename? Something else?

Comment: I am trying to modify the the open file so just go through an open text file and weed out all the comment lines. I hope this helps understand my question better sorry, I am not too familiar with terminology etc

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by the word "open". How is an open text file different from any other file in this context?

Comment: So open file would mean like I have a text file open on my desktop and I hit the "script" executable and it would remove all the comments from the current text file on my desktop that I have opened up.

Comment: Usually "open file" means something like you have it in a text editor.

Comment: ...so you want your script to look at which files you have open in a graphical editor? That's *really* not easy to do in a generic way (ie. that doesn't depend on using a specific editor).

Comment: Most text editors have built-in commands to do this kind of thing. Why do you need to do it in bash when you already have the file open?

Comment: How about just filtering the clipboard? Copy to the clipboard, run the script, and paste? It'd still require details about what OS you're using (since clipboard implementations vary), but that's easier than needing to inspect the state of any random editor you might happen to use.

Comment: anyhow, there's no conceivable answer that won't be OS-dependent here -- bash simply doesn't have any primitives that understand the GUI, or what an "editor" is, or so forth in a generic way. Thus, without more environment details [ie. specifying an operating system], an answer that's sure to work for the OP is hard to come by.

Comment: Well I didnt know what language to use really I have only used autoIT and Bash to create scripts and I was asked to create something to filter/remove comments from text files. Thanks for the replies everyone appreciate your time greatly. I will read more into sed and GNU( as i have no clue what they are).

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: okay, that rules out any xclip answer (unless you're running an X server for Windows -- they *do* exist -- and your editor is an X-based application). I believe cygwin has its own clipboard integration tool, if you are in fact using cygwin, but I'd have to look at what it is.

Comment: ...if you're talking about Microsoft's own bash-for-Windows, I have no idea if that has access to the Windows clipboard at all; wouldn't be surprised at all if it didn't. Frankly, AutoIT is likely the better tool for the job at hand.

Comment: ...in general, though, I'm inclined to agree with Barmar -- if your editor can't do this itself, you should think about using a better editor.

Comment: Roger that, thanks Duffy appreciate it. Will look for some editor with the capability.

Comment: Thanks Alot for the help boys figured out how to use regex with sublime text to remove the comments just like Barmar suggested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform this filter on a stream with `sed` is simple:

```
sed -e '/^\\\\/ d'
```

...however, integrating with a graphical editor (in a manner not specific to a single editor) is considerably less so.

---

To work with the clipboard on a platform where the GUI is based on X11 using `xclip`:

```
#!/bin/bash
xclip -o "$@" | sed -e '/^\\\\/ d' | xclip -i "$@"
```

...run with `-selection clipboard` or `-selection secondary` if the default of `-selection primary` doesn't use the same clipboard you're trying to edit (X has several different clipboards).